# get all the string before first numeric character python regex

Tags: python, regex

GC_DATA_TEXT_20200304.csv

get only

GC_DATA_TEXT

case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub` here:

```
inp = "GC_DATA_TEXT_20200304.csv"
out = re.sub(r'_\d{8}.*$', '', inp)
print(out)
```

Another possibility would be to split the string on the third underscore, and then join together again:

```
out = "_".join(inp.split("_", 3)[:3])
print(out)
```

Both print:

```
GC_DATA_TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text='GC_DATA_TEXT_20200304.csv'
pattern = r'(\D+)_'
matched_ans=re.findall(pattern,text)[0]
'GC_DATA_TEXT'
```

/D+ should match all non numeric characters